# Python Selenium Web Driver перебор логина / пароля из списка

Tags: python, selenium, список

Подскажите, как можно прописать простой перебор некорректных логинов/паролей для выполнения негативных тест-кейсов по списку.

1. Есть некий список, который содержит логины/пароли с недопустимыми символами, которые мы будем проверять:

   ```
   list = ["log in", "lögin", "login%"]
   ```

   и т.д. Можно, конечно, из файла импортировать, но списком проще.
2. У нас имеется поле Login, куда мы будем вставлять сначала первое значение из списка:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_id("Login").send_keys(list[0])
   ```
3. Жать кнопку ОК:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_id("OK_button").click()
   ```

   После этого ожидаемый результат, что в форме будет выводиться сообщение: `"The Login field has invalid format."` - т.е. всё идет по плану и нам не дают создать учётку с недопустимыми символами.
4. Я так понимаю, что для составления условия можно отталкивать от появляющегося на странице данного сообщения:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_link_text("The Login field has invalid format.")
   ```

После этого мы должны стереть логин в поле Login и подставить следующий по списку list:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Login").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("Login").send_keys(list[1])
driver.find_element_by_id("OK_button").click()
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как этот процесс сделать с меньшем количеством строк кода.

Прописывать для каждого значения из списка по три строчки не слишком продуктивное решение, особенно, если в списке может быть до сотни элементов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вынести все в функцию, а потом использовать списковое включение:

```
def check_login(login):
     driver.find_element_by_id("Login").send_keys(login)
     driver.find_element_by_id("OK_button").click()
     driver.find_element_by_link_text("The Login field has invalid format.")
     driver.find_element_by_id("Login").clear()
incorrect_logins = ["log in", "lögin", "login%"] # не стоит использовать list  в качестве имени переменной так как есть встроенная функция list.
[check_login(incorrect_login) for incorrect_login in incorrect_logins]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все заработало! Я до такого пока еще не дошел в изучении Питона...